# Warum unterscheidet sich das englische Ethnonym für »preußisch« vom Deutschen?

Tags: etymology, place-name

Man könnte die Frage wahrscheinlich durch diese verstehen: Warum reimen sich *Russian* und *Prussian*, aber *russisch* und *preußisch* nicht?

Mit anderen Worten: Was sind die historischen Gründe, weswegen *Preußen* und *preußisch* so schlecht ins Englisch übersetzt wurden? Hat man vielleicht im Mittelalter den ursprünglichen Preußen mit der Kiewer Rus verwechselt, und dann den Fehler nur später halbherzig korrigiert?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reu%C3%9Fen_(Volksstamm) früher reimte sich das schon.. Genauso wurde der Stamm in Preußen auch *Prußen* genannt. Der Englische Begriff für Preußen könnte früher entlehnt sein, oder gar überhaupt nicht aus dem Deutschen kommen (Polnisch wäre auch ne Option..).

Comment: Wictionary might help with the etymology https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Prussia https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Russia

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zunächst *Preußen.* Dieser Name leitet sich von einem [baltischen Volksstamm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pru%C3%9Fen) ab, dessen Eigenbezeichnung **Prūsai* (rekonstruiert aus dem Adjektiv *prūsiskan)* war. Dieser Stamm besiedelte das Gebiet, das in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts *Ostpreußen* genannt wurde. Im Mittelniederdeutschen wurde dieser Stamm als *Prûsse* bezeichnet, im Mittelhochdeutschen als *Priuzen*. Geläufige Latinisierungen waren *Pruzi, Prutheni* oder *Borussi* – aus letzterem leitet sich der Name vieler Fußballvereine ab.

Ob sich die Englische Variante (ehemals *Pruce,* später *Prussia)* nun von der mittelniederdeutschen oder einer Lateinischen Form ableitet ist unerheblich; er veränderte sich über die Jahrhunderte kaum. Die beiden deutschen Formen entwickelten sich jedoch analog zu vergleichbaren Wörtern wie [*ziugen*, *zeugen*](http://dwds.de/wb/zeugen#et-1). Das heißt, der *iu*-Diphthong wurde zu *eu,* womit aus den *Prußen Preußen* wurden. Eine Verwechslung irgendwelcher Bezeichnungen lag nie vor, die Sprachgeschichte war schlicht unterschiedlich.

Nun zu Russland, dessen Name, wie du bemerkt hast, von den Kiewer Rus abstammt. Auch dafür gab es Latinisierungen wie *Russia* und *Ruthenia*. Und vielleicht überrascht es auch nicht, dass die mittelhochdeutsche Form *Rûʒ* existiert hat. Neben der etablierte sich aber auch die Wurzel *Riuʒe*. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Russia#Etymology) behauptet, dass die englische Variante sich direkt von der Latinisierung *Russia* ableitet.

Auch das Wort *Riuʒe* nahm am oben angesprochenen Lautwandel teil. Daraus wurde der *Reuße* – [eine veraltete Variante des *Russen*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Russen%2CReussen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRussen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CReussen%3B%2Cc0). Letztlich hatte diese sprachnatürliche Form aber keine Chance gegen die »Übermacht« der sie umgebenden (slawischen, romanischen, skandinavischen …) Varianten mit *u*, weswegen die unverschobene Form *Russen* niemals ausstarb. Im Gegenteil, es traf die *Reußen*, die heute nicht mehr in Gebrauch sind und auch kaum mehr verstanden werden.

---

Fazit: Beide Wörter beruhen tatsächlich auf dem gleichen Stamm. *Preußen* folgt einer systematischen Lautverschiebung, die beim Übergang vom Mittel- zum Neuhochdeutschen durchgeführt wurde. Die systematische Form *Reußen* existierte, wurde jedoch von der »Rückborgung« *Russen* verdrängt.

Nicht *preußisch* wurde schlecht ins Englische übersetzt sondern *russisch* »schlecht« ins Deutsche zurückgeholt.

Comment: Hervorragende Antwort!

Comment: Gut zusammengefasst, wobei ich den Satz mit der *Übermacht der umgebenden Formen mit "u"* gerne besser belegt wüsste. So haben sich ja bspw. poln. *Rosja* und schwed. *Ryssland* auch gehalten - und nicht zu vergessen russ. *Rossija* (d.h. die Eigenbezeichnung weicht auch vom *u* ab).

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Prussia) sagt zu *Prussia*: "from Medieval Latin *Borussi*, *Prusi*". Aber wie Du schon geschrieben hast, kommt es darauf nicht an.